# TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined when trying to use first selection result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using autocomplete plugin to select university from an external json list. Now, it will be such that once student selects university, later he will need to choose his faculty.

For instance,

```
Columbia University: communityid = 11 : parentID = 0
Architecture, Planning & Preservation: communityid = 14 : parentid = 11
```

I dont understand why I am getting `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined` error.

```
<form action="content/signup/index.cs.asp?Process=AddMember" method="post" class="signup-form">
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="COMMUNITY" size="55" value="" title="<%=lngUniversity%>" />
      <div id="autobox"></div>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="SCHOOL" size="55" value="" title="<%=lngSchool%>" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="COMMUNITYEMAIL" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="COMMUNITYID" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="x" value="p">
      <input type="submit" name="#" value="<%=lngSubmit%>" class="btn btn-signup">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(".signup-form input[name='COMMUNITY']").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/content/signup/index.cs.asp?Process=CheckEmail&PARENTID=0&COMMUNITY=" + request.term,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data.CheckEmail, function (item) {
          return {
            label: item.Name,
            value: item.Name,
            CommunityID: item.CommunityID
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  }
});
$(".signup-form input[name='SCHOOL']").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/content/signup/index.cs.asp?Process=Check&PARENTID=" + $(".signup-form input[name='COMMUNITY']").data(CommunityID).selectedItem.UniversityId + "&COMMUNITY=" + request.term,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data.CheckEmail, function (item) {
          return {
            label: item.Name,
            value: item.Name,
            emailURL: item.emailURL,
            SchoolID: item.CommunityID
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 1,
  select: function (event, ui) {
    $(".signup-form input[name='COMMUNITYEMAIL']").val(ui.item.emailURL);
    $(".signup-form input[name='COMMUNITYID']").val(ui.item.CommunityID);
  },
  open: function () {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
  },
  close: function () {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
  },
  appendTo: '#autobox'
});
```

Comment: Why do you expect there to be data on `$(".signup-form input[name='COMMUNITY']")`?

Comment: Its a textbox. For example when user types "C", he will get the list of universities with Cs in their names (Clark university, columbia university, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before being sure that there is no problem regarding to the `JSON` data format, check if the related `javascript` files (i.e. `jquery-x.x.x`) are referenced properly (just once). This problem might occur when the related files are not referenced or referenced multiple times. Hope this helps...